# SQL Server crashes when remote query fails

Tags: sql-server-2005, linked-server, rpc

**Setup:**
I have a linked server setup on SQL Server 2005 which is pointing to an Oracle DB. The linked server has RPC enabled.

**Problem:** When a query throws an exception on the remote server (Oracle DB) the SQL Server instance crashes. The logs say that the crash was due to some problem with the RPC call. Is there a way in which I can prevent the entire server to collapse but also use RPC over my linked server.

**EDIT:** Event Log

SQL Server is terminating because of fatal exception c0000005. This error may be caused by an unhandled Win32 or C++ exception, or by an access violation encountered during exception handling. Check the SQL error log for any related stack dumps or messages. This exception forces SQL Server to shutdown. To recover from this error, restart the server (unless SQLAgent is configured to auto restart).

For more information, see Help and Support Center at http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/events.asp.

Comment: is the server rebooting, or just the SQL services?

Answer (score 1):

Contact Microsoft Support Services (PSS). Make sure the issue also happens on the most current version of your server (i.e. full updated service packs and patches). MS will gladly issue a patch free of charge for a production issue.

Regardless how you turn the table, a server should not crash on a RPC issue. Point. This is a bug you encountered that needs patching.

Answer (score 0):

What's the error that is being returned?  Check the mini dump files in the SQL Server Log folder to get more information about the actual reason for the crash.

You'll probably need to open a ticket with Microsoft and have look into the bugcheck that is causing the crash.

Before you call make sure you have the most recent service pack and hot fix installed.  That will be the first thing they want you to do.